# how to match string from the input and read it as number?

Tags: r

I am taking a string which is given as input and then match it with a number and return back the string as out put.

Example:

```
my.string <- readline(prompt="Enter string 1: ")

print(my.string)
#[1] "coffee"
```

DataFrame:

```
ID     name
22     coffee
23     tea
24     milk
```

Task :

> I need to convert 'coffee' into 22 because I want to pass this number into a
>   function.

How do I get that ?

Comment: Try `which(df$name == my.string)`. This will give you an index into `df$ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like my comment said, this is rather straightforward.

```
my.string <- readline(prompt="Enter string 1: ")

inx <- which(DataFrame$name == my.string)
DataFrame$ID[inx]
#[1] 22
```

**Data.**

```
DataFrame <- read.table(text = "
ID     name
22     coffee
23     tea
24     milk
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, if your `data.frame` has only 2 columns then using `named` vector would be an option worth considering. It provides easy way to subset.

It seems to me that `name` column is unique in your data.frame. If so then you can convert `name` column to `rownames` then selection will be much simpler.

```
#change the 'name' to rownames
rownames(df) <- df$name
df$name <- NULL

#Now selection will be much easier
df[my.string, "ID"]
#22
```

Using "named vector":

```
itemVector <- c(22,23,24)
names(itemVector) <- c("coffee", "tea", "milk")
itemVector[my.string]
# coffee 
# 22
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
                  "ID     name
                  22     coffee
                  23     tea
                  24     milk",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```